# rebar3 doesnt compile erlydtl file

Tags: templates, erlang, rebar3, erlydtl

I have a problem which my rebar3 does not compile the erlydtl files (.dtl) and I have looking around for a while but not solution. Previously it worked, but after I upgrade erlang to the newest version, the *.dtl file is not compiled and `sync:on_sync` does not work neight.

Anyone here have any idear on that?

Here is my rebar.conf file

```
{erl_opts, [debug_info]}.
{deps, [
    {sync, {git, "https://github.com/rustyio/sync.git" , {branch, "master"}}},
    {erlydtl, {git, "https://github.com/erlydtl/erlydtl.git", { branch, "master"}}},
    {jsx, {git, "https://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx.git", {branch, "main"}}},
    {epgsql, {git, "https://github.com/epgsql/epgsql.git"}},
    {gen_smtp, {git, "https://github.com/gen-smtp/gen_smtp.git", {branch, "master"}}},
    {cowboy, { git, "https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy.git", {branch, "master"}}},
    poolboy
]}.

{erlydtl_opts, [
    {doc_root, "src/templates"}
    %{outdir, "ebin"},
    %{compiler_options, [report, return, debug_info]},
    %{source_ext, ".dtl"}
    %% {module_ext, "_view"}
]}.

{provider_hooks, [
    {pre_hooks, [{compile, {erlydtl, compile}}]}
]}.

{relx, [
    {release, {core, "0.1.0"}, [
        core, poolboy, erlydtl,
        account, realestate, realestate_admin,
        sync, sasl, epgsql, jsx, gen_smtp
    ]},
    {mode, dev},

    %% automatically picked up if the files
    %% exist but can be set manually, which
    %% is required if the names aren't exactly
    %% sys.config and vm.args
    {sys_config, "./config/sys.config"},
    {vm_args, "./config/vm.args"}

    %% the .src form of the configuration files do
    %% not require setting RELX_REPLACE_OS_VARS
    %% {sys_config_src, "./config/sys.config.src"},
    %% {vm_args_src, "./config/vm.args.src"}
]}.

{profiles, [
    {prod, [
        {relx, [
            %% prod is the default mode when prod
            %% profile is used, so does not have
            %% to be explicitly included like this
            {mode, prod}

            %% use minimal mode to exclude ERTS
            %% {mode, minimal}
        ]}
    ]}
]}.

{dialyzer, [
    %% Warns the undefined type or unknown function
    {warnings, [ unknown ]}
]}.

{xref_checks, [
    %% enable most checks, but avoid 'unused calls' which is often
    %% very verbose
    undefined_function_calls, undefined_functions, locals_not_used,
    deprecated_function_calls, deprecated_functions
]}.

{plugins, [ 
    % {rebar3_auto, {git, "https://github.com/xuchaoqian/rebar3-auto.git", {branch, "master"}}}
]}.
```

Thanks,

Comment: Did you mange to compile the .dtl files ?, I'm having the same issue with OTP 25